# Getting an image from s3 bucket and displaying in blade.php Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-s3

i'm new to Laravel and i'm trying to get an image from Amazon s3 bucket to display on my website, but i get a FileNotFoundException error. Any Help would be appreciated.

My route:

```
Route::get('s3-image-upload','S3ImageController@getImage');
```

Controller:

```
public static function getImage (Request $imagePath)
{
        return Storage::disk('s3')->get($imagePath);
}
```

View:

```
{!!Html::image(getImage($myPath)!!}
```

Comment: you must add public permission in your S3...

Comment: @Ramadhan I already made it public by adding a bucket policy to make it public.                                                                                                       {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Sid": "AddPerm",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": "*",
          "Action": "s3:GetObject",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
      }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

`$imagePath` is a `Request` instance, not the image URL. You need to get the URL from the request. Assuming you have a field named `filename` in the request:

```
public static function getImage (Request $request)
{
    $filename = Input::get("filename"); // OR
    $filename = $request->get("filename");
    return Storage::disk('s3')->get($filename);
}
```

- [`Illuminate\Http\Request` reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do not have a field. But if removed the Request it is giving me an error: Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\S3ImageController::getImage()

Comment: Don't remove the `Request`. Use it to get the field you need like the snippet I wrote in my answer. What do you mean you don’t have a field? Where do you intend to get the image name from then?

Comment: I'm kinda confuse, I'm gonna just explain my objective. I currently have some images uploaded in s3 but i'm trying to pull an image according to the user which has logged into the website that i am making. Like displaying the correct profile picture for each user.

Comment: That's a lot different. If you use the code in my example, if you go to `website.com/s3-image-upload?filename=image.jpg` it should show the image *image.jpg* from the bucket. Retrieving user information is another topic entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an accessor like follow to get Image URL

It returns URL to the image and you can access it by $profile->image

```
public function getImageAttribute($value)
{
    if ($value) {

        return Storage::disk('s3')->url($value);
    }

    return "https://source.unsplash.com/96x96/daily";
}
```

I assume you save image as follow

```
$path = $request->file('image')->store('images', 's3');
        
Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($path, 'public');

$profile->update([
      'image' =>  $path
      ]);
```

You can check this commit for more detail

https://github.com/itxshakil/ediary/commit/23cb4b1cb7b8a4eac68f534e8c5b6897abc6421a